# Excel Random Numbers dependend on week

Tags: excel, algorithm, function, random, numbers

I have a problem in excel and i am not sure how to solve that or if thats even possible. I want to create a certain amount of random numbers, lets say from 1 till 20. So i would use the RANDBETWEEN(1;20) function. But of course the numbers are always changing. I want that the numbers are getting newly generated dependent on the day or week. For example if i open the excel file in a certain week the function will always create the same numbers. If i open it in the next week there will be other numbers. But during one week the numbers should be the same. So a creation of random numbers depending on the calendar wekk. How would you do that? Is that possible?
Looking forward to your input. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no way to do this with an Excel function. With VBA it would be possible though. But maybe it is more practical if you generate a long list of random numbers in a hidden sheet, and then you could grab a section from that list via a formula, depending on the week. Would that be an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: Also, how many is *a certain amount of random numbers*?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

Create a new sheet which you would optionally hide later. It would contain a long list of random generated numbers in 53 columns -- one column per week -- and as many rows you need, let's say 100 rows. So you'll have a matrix of random numbers in the range A1:BA100.

At first you would generate these numbers with `=RANDBETWEEN(1;20)`, but to avoid that these numbers are regenerated every time you open the file, you should then select them all, and paste them again, but only as values (choose "Paste - Paste Values" from the menu). This will remove the formula and make the numbers hard-coded.

For ease of use, you could give that range a name (with workbook scope), let's say "random". At this stage that sheet is ready, and you could optionally hide it now.

Then in your main sheet, you could enter a formula like this:

```
=INDEX(random; ROW(); WEEKNUM(NOW()))
```

This will use the cell's row number and the current week number as row/column in the "random" range, and retrieve the number from that table at that position. If you drag that formula down, you actually get a column of data from the "random" table.

As the "random" range data is fixed, you'll get the same data in the above formula if the week number does not change.

Comment: @PSchmid, did this answer your question? Could you give some feed-back?